# Closure compiler added '--' to my Javascript function. What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a simple function that I ran through [Google's Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code):

```
var fisherYatesShuffle = function(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length;
  var temporaryValue;
  var randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
};
```

It gave me back the following (which I've pretty-printed):

```
var fisherYatesShuffle = function(a) {
  for (var b = a.length, d, c; 0 !== b;) c = Math.floor(Math.random() * b), --
    b, d = a[b], a[b] = a[c], a[c] = d;
  return a
};
```

What is this 'dash dash' rass at the end of line two? Why have I never seen it?

Comment: It means `currentIndex -= 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `--
    b` which is `--b` pre-decrement operator.

Same as

```
b = b - 1;
```

It is split on the next line, because there are already 80 characters(max) on that line.